# Issue importing service provider via file configuration WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am working to import a service provider into my WSO2 Identity Server using the "file configuration" feature.  The file I am importing from has a claim called "Local Claim"

**Configuration Screenshot**

[image]

**Configuration XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ServiceProvider>
  <ApplicationName>Local Claim SP</ApplicationName>
  <Description/>
  <InboundAuthenticationConfig>
    <InboundAuthenticationRequestConfigs>
      <InboundAuthenticationRequestConfig>
        <InboundAuthKey>Local Claim SP</InboundAuthKey>
        <InboundAuthType>openid</InboundAuthType>
        <InboundConfigType>standardAPP</InboundConfigType>
        <Properties/>
      </InboundAuthenticationRequestConfig>
      <InboundAuthenticationRequestConfig>
        <InboundAuthKey>Local Claim SP</InboundAuthKey>
        <InboundAuthType>passivests</InboundAuthType>
        <InboundConfigType>standardAPP</InboundConfigType>
        <Properties/>
      </InboundAuthenticationRequestConfig>
    </InboundAuthenticationRequestConfigs>
  </InboundAuthenticationConfig>
  <LocalAndOutBoundAuthenticationConfig>
    <AuthenticationSteps/>
    <AuthenticationType>default</AuthenticationType>
    <alwaysSendBackAuthenticatedListOfIdPs>false</alwaysSendBackAuthenticatedListOfIdPs>
    <UseTenantDomainInUsername>false</UseTenantDomainInUsername>
    <UseUserstoreDomainInRoles>true</UseUserstoreDomainInRoles>
    <UseUserstoreDomainInUsername>false</UseUserstoreDomainInUsername>
    <EnableAuthorization>false</EnableAuthorization>
  </LocalAndOutBoundAuthenticationConfig>
  <RequestPathAuthenticatorConfigs/>
  <InboundProvisioningConfig>
    <ProvisioningUserStore/>
    <IsProvisioningEnabled>false</IsProvisioningEnabled>
    <IsDumbModeEnabled>false</IsDumbModeEnabled>
  </InboundProvisioningConfig>
  <OutboundProvisioningConfig>
    <ProvisioningIdentityProviders/>
  </OutboundProvisioningConfig>
  <ClaimConfig>
    <RoleClaimURI/>
    <LocalClaimDialect>false</LocalClaimDialect>
    <IdpClaim/>
    <ClaimMappings>
      <ClaimMapping>
        <LocalClaim>
          <ClaimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/localClaim</ClaimUri>
          <claimId>0</claimId>
        </LocalClaim>
        <RemoteClaim>
          <ClaimUri>Local Claim</ClaimUri>
          <claimId>0</claimId>
        </RemoteClaim>
        <RequestClaim>true</RequestClaim>
        <MandatoryClaim>false</MandatoryClaim>
      </ClaimMapping>
    </ClaimMappings>
    <AlwaysSendMappedLocalSubjectId>false</AlwaysSendMappedLocalSubjectId>
    <SPClaimDialects/>
  </ClaimConfig>
  <PermissionAndRoleConfig>
    <Permissions/>
    <RoleMappings/>
    <IdpRoles/>
  </PermissionAndRoleConfig>
  <IsSaaSApp>false</IsSaaSApp>
</ServiceProvider>
```

**When I try to import the XML file, I get the following error:**

[image]

I looked at my local claims on the Identity Server I am trying to import to and I have the local claim that the error is referencing.

[image]

That error message doesn't make sense to me.  Am I misunderstanding what a local claim is?  I thought adding a claim to the `http://wso2.org/claims` dialect is how you add a local claim.  So why is it throwing an error about a claim that I have in the dialect?

Comment: I couldn't able to reproduce this one. Can you make sure there is no space character in the created claim URI value? Because when I tried with a tailing space I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you have not created the claim `http://wso2.org/claims/localClaim` in the Identity Server you are importing this SP into. So what you need to do is add the required local claim by navigating to `Claims -> Add -> Add Local Claim`

After doing this try to import the service provider again.

Comment: Please see the image at the bottom of my post.  I have created the local claim already.